# How can I get a column from a related database in Notion?

Tags: notion-api, notion, notion.net

I am working on a database to organize my medical calendar. I am migrating something that I already had done on Google Sheets to Notion.

But I came across the following problem: I want to create a view that has a column obtained from another table.

Let's get to the specific case:
I have a database called "Centros medicos" which has a column called "Direccion"
From my "Consultas" database, I have a relationship with "Centros medicos" but it only shows me the name. I want to see the "direccion" of the medical center without having to click.

I hope you understood :)

I will leave some photos to explain:

[image]

[image]

I tried to create filters and an intermediate database. I also tried using views, but I couldn't find any information on Google about how to do what I'm trying to do.

In Google Sheets, I achieve this using a function called VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

You make a rollup property for that, select the database in the rollup and the property of that database that you want to display.